# How to post a new entry to the help menu with python

Tags: python, interface

I am making an updater for blender and I want add "Update Blender" entry to the Help menu. How I do that ?

I know about the menu template , I know how to make the menu, my question is how I inject it to the bottom of the Help menu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a custom menu drawing function, accepting two arguments: the parent `Menu` object and context access object.

```
def draw_help_item(self, context):
    self.layout.operator('wm.new_help_item', text = "New Help Item")
```

Then either `append` or `prepend` the function to the menu's class upon registering the new class, and `remove` it when unregistering:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.append(draw_help_item)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.remove(draw_help_item)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

The appropriate class' name, in this case `bpy.types.INFO_MT_add`, can be searched in Python shell assisted by autocompletion. It's usually prefixed with the area type, then either `_MT` for menu or `_HT` for header, and is fairly easy to deduce which UI element it corresponds with.